# RDA non-significant RDA axes

Tags: r, significance, rda

I have looked online forums and through various papers and am a little stumped on the interpretation of my results for RDA analysis.

I ran the full model with genetic cluster at the condition and came up with a significant model with a global test using permutations of the anova (PERMANOVA) using the anova.cca() function.

```
signif.full.c <- anova.cca(gno.rda.c)
signif.full.c
#Permutation test for rda under reduced model
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Model: rda(formula = gen.imp ~ long + lat + Depth + Condition(Clusters), data = gno.clusters, scale = T)
#Df Variance      F Pr(>F)  
#Model      4    221.0 1.0546  0.007 **
#  Residual 100   5239.3
```

Then I look at the RDA axes, which none are significant:

```
signif.axis.c <- anova.cca(gno.rda.c, by="axis")
signif.axis.c
#Permutation test for rda under reduced model
#Forward tests for axes
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Model: rda(formula = gen.imp ~ long + lat + Depth + Condition(Clusters), data = gno.clusters, scale = T)
#Df Variance      F Pr(>F)
#RDA1       1     58.0 1.1078  0.123
#RDA2       1     56.3 1.0740  0.307
#RDA3       1     55.3 1.0549  0.302
#RDA4       1     51.4 0.9816  0.686
#Residual 100   5239.3
```

But, looking the "margin" permutations which looks at the significance of the of terms, I get significant results for longitude and depth:

```
signif.margin.c <- anova.cca(gno.rda.c, by="margin")
signif.margin.c
#Permutation test for rda under reduced model
#Marginal effects of terms
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Model: rda(formula = gen.imp ~ long + lat + Depth + Condition(Clusters), data = gno.clusters, scale = T)
#Df Variance      F Pr(>F)  
#long       1     56.2 1.0717  0.027 *
#  lat        1     53.9 1.0285  0.214  
#Depth      2    112.8 1.0762  0.007 **
#  Residual 100   5239.3
```

I remove lattitude from the models and again the model is significant as well as the terms, but again the RDA axes are not significant:

```
#Permutation test for rda under reduced model
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Model: rda(formula = gen.imp ~ long + Depth + Condition(Clusters), data = gno.clusters, scale = T)
#Df Variance     F Pr(>F)  
#Model      3    167.1 1.063  0.005 **
#  Residual 101   5293.2  

#Permutation test for rda under reduced model
#Marginal effects of terms
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Model: rda(formula = gen.imp ~ long + Depth + Condition(Clusters), data = gno.clusters, scale = T)
#Df Variance      F Pr(>F)  
#long       1     55.9 1.0657  0.039 *
#  Depth      2    112.4 1.0719  0.015 *
#  Residual 101   5293.2  

#Permutation test for rda under reduced model
#Forward tests for axes
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Model: rda(formula = gen.imp ~ long + Depth + Condition(Clusters), data = gno.clusters, scale = T)
#Df Variance      F Pr(>F)
#RDA1       1     57.1 1.0900  0.165
#RDA2       1     56.0 1.0681  0.178
#RDA3       1     54.0 1.0308  0.245
#Residual 101   5293.2
```

Does this mean that I can ignore the model significance and the term significance because the RDA axes are not significant?

Comment: Might be  better off looking to the crossvalidated stack site - that's where to go for stats advice

Comment: @rg255 thanks! Should I just post the question again or is there a way to link it?